# Getting Discharge Safety from a Battery

Tags: batteries, calculation, lifetime

I would like to calculate the battery runtime for an ESP32, using a 18650 battery with 2600 mAh ([Datasheet](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/001499575DS01/datasheet-1499575-sony-us18650vtc5a-non-standard-battery-rechargeable-18650-high-current-loading-flat-top-li-ion-37-v-2600-mah.pdf)).

When I am using a calculator such as this [one](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/battery-life#how-to-calculate-the-battery-runtime), it requires me to put in a discharge safety value. How can I get/calculate that?

Using the battery I have right now, the cutoff voltage is around 3 V (from experience) and I can charge the battery up to 4.2 V. But how would I get the % value?

The ESP is sending some sensor data via LoRa and will then go to (deep) sleep:

| Mode | Avg. Consumption | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deep Sleep | ~ 6.4 µA | 300s |
| Up | ~ 4.1 mA | 20s |

Thanks & BR!

Comment: At what current(s) are you draining the battery?  Is it a constant current or variable?  How bad is it if the equipment shuts itself off (on a scale of "my desk light goes out" to "my heart stops").  Please _edit your question_ with these details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value from the characteristic discharge curves of the battery, as seen on page 5 of the datasheet you linked: At low discharge rate (0.5A), the cell will reach 3V after 2400mAh have been drained from it. That's 92.3% of the cell's nominal capacity, with 7.7% (200mAh) of the stored charge remaining in the cell.